# gitlab-rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production fails with Permission error

Tags: gitlab

I installed GitLab 7.7.2 on CentOS 7 and successfully installed.

Now I tried to run GitLab in subdirectory style such as http://url/gitlab.

I looked into this file and changed as this instruction.
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config

Then I precompiled and got error.

```
# gitlab-rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
I, [2015-02-27T17:35:18.980208 #4864]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/assets/authbuttons/github_32-199ebcd7adccbfe20068d39bfd57e6bf.png
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/assets/authbuttons/github_32-199ebcd7adccbfe20068d39bfd57e6bf.png+

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, changing files directly will cause them to be rewritten after a `reconfigure`. When calling `gitlab-rake` you don't have to state the `RAILS_ENV` it is taken care of by the `gitlab-rake` wrapper.

Now as far as the relative url option is concerned, this is not yet implemented in the omnibus package.

Comment: I changed 4 files,  gitlab.yml.erb,  unicorn.rb.erb,  gitlab-shell-config.yml.erb and  nginx-gitlab-http.conf.erb in
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default.

gitlab.yml.erb ----- add "relative_url_root: /gitlab"

unicorn.rb.erb ----- add "ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab""

 gitlab-shell-config.yml.erb ----- changed "gitlab_url: "<%= @api_url %>/gitlab/""

 nginx-gitlab-http.conf.erb ----- changed "location /gitlab {"

And then, I reconfigure and I finally got subdirectory.

Answer (score 6):

[This post](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/492) describes a nice workaround. Similar to what [user Perceval FARAMAZ suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28786777/923794) we can open up the permissions *temporarily* for compiling new and changed assets, and then close them down again.

By using ACLs, instead of standard bits, this is done only for the git user, and without actually changing the ownership from `root:root`:

```
# ... hack on CSS ...

# Need to let user `git` write to assets/ because gitlab-rake tries to write
# to it as `git`, while `assets/` is owned by root.
apt-get install acl
setfacl -R -m u:git:rwX /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/assets/
gitlab-rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
chmod -R a+rX /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/assets/

# Remove git's write access
setfacl -R -x u:git /opt
```

This works for both adding new images, as well as changing existing assets.

Comment: nice answer, it helped me a lot. Thx

Answer (score 3):

`chmod -R 1777 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/assets` did the trick for me.

It sets the permissions on full read/write/execute for everybody, and sets the sticky bit on 't' (nobody can delete the directory except root/the file owner, thus allowing rake to do its stuff).

Comment: Opening up permissions to everyone is a security issue. After installation/changes close the permissions down again